# In which order will the elements of Scala Buffer be accessed in a for loop?

Tags: scala

```
for(elt <- bufferObject: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer)
  // Do something with the element of the collection
```

In which order will the elements in the for loop be accessed ? Randomly ?

From the Scala API one can see that Buffer is a subclass of Seq, in which the elements are ordered. Does this also hold for the loop above ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a selection of the super-types of `mutable.Buffer[A]`, and the traversal guarantees they provide:

- `Seq[A]` -- All elements have a position, with an index associated; they are always traversed one by one, from lowest index to highest index.
- `GenSeq[A]` -- All elements have a position, with an index associated; they may be traversed one by one or in parallel; if a new collection is generated, the position of the elements in the new collection will correspond to the old collection, even if the traversal is in parallel.
- `Iterable[A]` -- Elements may be traversed in any order, but will always be traversed in the same order (that is, it can't change from one iteration to another); they'll be traversed one by one.
- `GenIterable[A]` -- Elements may be traversed in any order, but will always be traversed in the same order (that is, it can't change from one iteration to another); traversal may happen one by one or in paralllel;  if a new collection is generated, the position of the elements in the new collection will correspond to the old collection, even if the traversal is in parallel.
- `Traversable[A]` -- Same guarantees as `Iterable[A]`, with the additional limitation that you can interrupt traversal, but you cannot determine when the next element will be choosen (which you can in `Iterable[A]` and descendants, by producing an `Iterator`).
- `GenTraversable[A]` -- Same guarantees as `GenIterable[A]`, with the additional limitation that you can interrupt traversal, but you cannot determine when the next element will be choosen (which you can in `GenIterable[A]` and descendants, by producing an `Iterator`).
- `TraversableOnce[A]` -- Same guarantees as in `Traversable[A]`, with the additional limitation that you might not be able to traverse the elements more than once.
- `GenTraversableOnce[A]` -- Same guarantees as in `GenTraversable[A]`, with the additional limitation that you might not be able to traverse the elements more than once.

Now, all guarantees apply, with the fewer limitations, which effectively means that everything said about `Seq[A]` holds true for `mutable.Buffer[A]`.

Now, to the for loop:

```
for(elt <- bufferObject: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer)
  doSomething(elt)
```

is the same thing as:

```
bufferObject.foreach(elt => dosomething(elt))
```

And

```
for(elt <- bufferObject: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer)
yield makeSomething(elt)
```

is the same thing as:

```
bufferObject.map(elt => makeSomething(elt))
```

In fact, *all* `for` variants will be translated into methods available on `Buffer` (or whatever other type you have there), so the guarantees provided by the collections all apply. Note, for instance, that a `GenSeq` used with `map` (for-yield) may process all elements in parallel, but will produce a collection where `newCollection(i) == makeSomething(bufferObject(i))`, that is, the indices are preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Should be ordered. `Buffer` defaults to `ArrayBuffer` I believe.

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer
import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer

scala> val x = Buffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> for (y <- x) println(y)
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: I think you meant that the default implementation of Buffer *is* ArrayBuffer, as indicated by `= ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `for`-comprehension will desugar to some combination of `map`, `flatMap`, and `foreach`, and these all follow the `Seq`'s defined order.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using parallel collections (via `par` method), the order of operations (like for comprehension, map, foreach and other sequential methods) in mutable Buffer is guaranteed.

Comment: If you're using parallel collections, you're no longer using `Buffer`

Comment: @Luigi Fair point, this will be `ParSeq`, but if somebody doing it, for example, in for comprehension, conversion is likely will be hidden from user.